# Show autocomplete suggestions for Developer Toolbar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, firefox-developer-tools

In the screenshot below (Firefox 39), the Developer Toolbar prompt (the one shown on Shift+F2, not the prompt of the (Web) Console raised with Ctrl-Shift-K, which is also shown above the Developer Toolbar prompt), can be seen to imply to offer autocomplete options:

[image: test.png]

.. since it suggests `--clipboard` as soon as `--` is typed as `[options]`, and it shows an "Available options" callout. But no matter what I do, I cannot see a list of suggestions for these "Available options" (tried clicking on the callout, pressing Enter, Ctrl-Enter, Shift-Enter).

So how can these "Available options", of the Developer Toolbar, be seen (specifically here for the `screenshot` command, which is not available from the Web Console)? (Note that in the Web Console, autocomplete suggestions are shown fine in a list, as expected)

Answer (score 0):

#### How can these "Available options", of the Developer Toolbar, be seen?

- <kbd>up arrow</kbd> and <kbd>down arrow</kbd> will scroll through the list of suggestions.
- <kbd>tab</kbd> will select the current suggestion.

Here is the output from `help screenshot` which shows the available options:

[image]

In your example using `screenshot filename.png --`, `--clipboard` is the first matching option:

- If you use <kbd>up arrow</kbd> and <kbd>down arrow</kbd> you will see the other choices.
- If you press <kbd>tab</kbd> you will see:

[image]

---

#### How do I use the Developer Toolbar command line?

> **Using the command line**
>
> Like a normal command line, you execute commands by typing them at the
>   prompt and pressing Enter.
>
> As you type, the Developer Toolbar suggests a possible completion to
>   your command.
>
> If there is more than one possible completion, the Up and Down arrow
>   keys cycle through the suggestions. Pressing Tab selects the current
>   suggestion.
>
> Pressing F1 will display all the suggestions in a list, with a summary
>   of what each command will do:
>
> [image]
>
> Typing `help <command>` will give you the help for `<command>`.
>
> The article continues with a list of the possible commands.

Source [Developer Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI)